# Texture glitch when using simple pixel shader

Tags: texture, rendering, pixel-shader, hlsl, artifacts

I have an issue with rendering my textures in Silverlight. When I look at it from above everything looks fine:

[image]

But if I only change angle of watching it it looks terrible:

[image]

I am using very simple pixel shader (hlsl):

```
float4 main(VsOutput vertex) : COLOR
{
        float4 texColor = tex2D(textureSampler, texCoord);

        return texColor;
}
```

If I don' t use that pixel shader and load texture via BasicEffect like:

```
BasicEffect.texture = myTexture
```

Everything looks fine. Why my pixel shader affects texture so bad?

---

I expect that it might be somehow connected with mipmapping, but I am not sure - my texture is pretty small so I guess it shouldn' t have such a big effect. Anyway I need some advices :).

---

Comment: I think you need anisotropic texture sampling

Comment: Please attach your shader completely, it's variable definition I mean, may be you need to define a High precision or mid precision variable instead of lowp

Comment: It migh be an issue with the texture filtering you're using. Which filter is it? Point, bilininear, trilinear? Also, make sure you did compute the correct mipmaps for the texture.

Comment: @AlanWolfe You were right! I will add some proper answer - hope you don' t mind :)  Lman I am using floats everywhere, but suggestion above solved the problem anyway. Glampert As I sad I think I don't compute mipmaps at all (I think because it might be done by default somewhere, but I don' t know about it :) I used "LinearWrap" sampler state if that's what you mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I followed Alan Wolfe suggestion (in comment to my question) And turned out he was right. I was using `SamplerState.LinearWrap` and that was the issue. When I changed this to `AnisotropicWrap` it looked much better. Below are some examples of different sampling types and how they affect texture:

```
graphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.PointWrap;
```

[image]

```
graphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;
```

[image]

```
graphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.AnisotropicWrap;
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to help! Anisotropic filtering is more expensive than bilinear. If that becomes a problem for you, you might try a  higher resolution texture, or distance field textures since it looks to be just 2 colors.  http://blog.demofox.org/2014/06/30/distance-field-textures/